# Laravel return specific model attribute

Tags: laravel

Let's say I have User Model.  Each User has `Pet` model.

both have relationship setup correctly.

When I get the user data along with his pets, I do this:

```
return $this->with('pets');
```

but what if I want to return the pet `name` only with the user data?
I've been trying that:

```
return $this->with('pets.name');
```

Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Model

```
 Class User extends Model ()
 {         
          ...
          public function pets()
           {
              return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Pet');
           }
 }
```

Controller or Repository or any other object

```
  function getUserDetails (Request $request) 
   {
         $userId = $request->get('id');
        $findUserById = User::find($userId);
        $fullName = $findUserById->pets->fullname;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way :

```
$users_with_pet_name = DB::table('users')
        ->join('pets', 'users.id', '=', 'pets.user_id')
        ->select('users.*', 'pets.name')
        ->get();
```

Check out joins section: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins